# Finding duration between ISO 8601 times

Tags: python, iso8601

I have a dataset, myTable, that has ISO 8601 time/date values. It looks like this:

```
username    minTime                     maxTime
Alice       2018-09-24T17:49:31.67Z     2018-10-03T20:07:05.216Z
John        2018-08-13T17:38:21.37Z     2018-10-03T20:04:15.312Z
```

I want to find the time duration (the difference between maxTime and minTime for each username). I checked out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23886140/parse-iso-8601-durations) but it only applies to C++ and requires using regex. I was wondering if there was a simpler way or library function that could find the time duration in ISO 8601 format?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to parse string in to `datetime` object. Once you have a `datetime` object, you can simply subtract them,

```
diff = maxTime - minTime
```